# PHP mysqli result works once with a function, but not a second time with a different function

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a php page where I am generating a json file out of a set of SQL queries. The results are then sent to a function that builds an array (person_checker and status_indicator are functions that I know work).

```
function array_builder($result, $id_name, $column_name, $type, $color)
    {
        global $mysqli;

        while ($row = $result->fetch_array())
        {

            $type_construct = $type . $row[$id_name];

            switch ($type)
                {
                case "work":
                    person_checker($row);
                    $url_color = status_indicator($row,$type)[0];
                    $link = status_indicator($row,$type)[1];
                    $new_type = $type;
                    $new_color = $color;
                    break;

                case "other_work":
                    person_checker($row);
                    $url_color = status_indicator($row,$type)[0];
                    $link = status_indicator($row,$type)[1];
                    $new_type = $type;
                    $new_color = $color;
                    break;

                case "person":
                    $url_color = status_indicator($row,$type)[0];
                    $link = status_indicator($row,$type)[1];
                    $new_type = $type;
                    $new_color = $color;
                    break;

                default:
                    $url_color = 'aliceblue';
                    $link = NULL;
                    $new_color = $color;
                    $new_type = $type;
                }

                $item_array= array(
                'id' => $type_construct,
                'name' => $name,
                'type' => $new_type,
                'color' => $new_color,
                'url_color' => $url_color,
                'link' => $link,
                );

                array_push($GLOBALS['array'], $item_array);

         }
}
```

This all works fine.  But I need to run the result again once the array has been built to generate links between the items in the array, and my function to do so does not generate any results:

```
function link_builder($result,$source_type,$target_type,$source_id,$target_id) {

    global $mysqli;
    global $person_color;
    global $multiple_author_color;
    global $otherwork_other_color;
    global $otherwork_lydgate_color;

    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {

    var_dump($result);
    echo"<br>";

    $source_location = array_search_multidim($GLOBALS['array'],'id',$source_type . $row[$source_id]);

    $target_location = array_search_multidim($GLOBALS['array'],'id',$target_type . $row[$target_id]);

    $color = $GLOBALS['array'][$target_location]['color'];

        $array = array(
        'color' => $color,
        'source' => $GLOBALS['array'][$source_location]['id'],
        'target' => $GLOBALS['array'][$target_location]['id'],
        'value' => 1);

        if (in_array_r($array,$GLOBALS['link_array']))
        {}
        else
        {
            array_push($GLOBALS['link_array'],$array);
        }
    }
}
```

I thought it might be one of the functions I wrote that are used in it, but even if I strip everything down to just the `var_dump` I still get no result. The object still exists, as I can dump it at the beginning and end of the page and get the same result in both places: `object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(3) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(8) ["type"]=> int(0) }` I can see other people have had this problem but none of the solutions suggested are working.  What am I doing wrong, or is there something going on with mysqli that I don't know about?  I'd rather not make another set of SQL calls, which is what my current version of this page does.

Comment: once you've 'walked' through a result set you'd need to reset it's pointer to the beginning with [mysqli::data_seek](http://cz.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.data-seek.php)

Comment: So in your case it would be a `$result->data_seek(0)` _before_ the while loop. (assuming `$result` is a `mysqli_result` Object)

Comment: That did the trick!  Thank you so much.  If you want to write up a formal answer I'd like to mark it as accepted.

Comment: @rickdenhaan already wrote a very good answer. I could only just copy that and couldn't be better, which makes no sense. So you can accept his answer!

Comment: Ok, cool.  I just know people get weird and testy about the upvotes sometimes so I didn't want to make you feel like I was slighting you.  Thanks again!

Comment: yeah, it would be true if @rickdenhann would have just copied my comments (as it happens), but he made a good comprehensive answer out of it. Also it could have been that he didn't see my comments. He deserves the accaptence anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you run the first function, you've run through the entire result set. When you run the second function and pass in the same `mysqli_result` object, its internal pointer is already set to the end, so calling `$result->fetch_array()` will yield no (more) results.

Fortunately, the fix is simple: you need to rewind the result set between your function calls so that you can loop through the result set again:

```
array_builder($result, $id_name, $column_name, $type, $color);
$result->data_seek(0);
link_builder($result, $source_type, $target_type, $source_id, $target_id);
```

Note the following from [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php):

> **Note:**
>
> This function can only be used with buffered results attained from the use of the [mysqli_store_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php) or [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) functions.

If your result came from a prepared statement and you get `$result` by calling `$stmt->get_result()`, you need to change that to use `$stmt->store_result()` in order to get a *buffered* result set instead of a regular result set and (optionally, shouldn't be necessary unless your app is running near the server's memory limits) call `$stmt->free_result()` afterwards to free up the memory used by the buffered results.

Comment: I should stop writing (short) answers as comment. Good, comprehensive answer! +1